# A issue with my computer,strange

Tags: user-interface, windows-10, computer-science

what's the matter with it? Windows10
sometimes , I open my computer(laptop),the application's icon will be strange,just like,the picture below.
but once i fresh the desktop them may be normal. if i continue freshing,them may be abnormal instead.
and my source manager will can not open just like the third picture below.
I had already tried to solve this problem but it didn't work.
who knows the problem?
I am so sorry that i don't have 10 reputation point to post image

Comment: This question is offtopic on Stackoverflow: it should be migrated to [su]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i know what you mean. I think all your desktop icons are a white. It's usually fixed by using CCleaner which can be downloaded here: https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download

And you also need around 1 gigabyte of free data on your C:\ drive. If the problem still persists then i recommend you to clean the icon cache:

https://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting

Comment: I will try it ,but i cant give you feedback to you right away,because it needs time to know "if it will work" because my laptop sometimes show this issue..